# Description Resource Path Location Type make: *** [main.o] Error -1073741502 taha C/C++ Problem

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, embedded

I am trying to make project for AVR in Eclipse and when I build the code, it can't build and show me that
it is grazy i have been trying for along time and i can't to solve my problem . i reinstall the eclipse and and i make sure that everything goes right

Comment: What does "crazy" mean?  You have provided no information that would allow anyone to answer.  Have you installed and configured the AVR toolchain? Can you build code with that toolchain independently of Eclipse.  Eclipse alone is insufficient to build C or C++ code for AVR targets, but you have only mentioned Eclipse. You need bother the CDT plug-in and an AVR toolchain, and to have configured Eclipse to use it.

Comment: Do this https://www.instructables.com/How-to-get-started-with-Eclipse-and-AVR ask questions in SO referencing this and any step that you are having trouble with, and pasting in any error messages you receive.

Comment: Copy the error message (in fact the complete build log, not just the last line) using plain-text markup into your question, not the title.  Your error message is coming from your toolchain, not from Eclipse.  Reinstalling Eclipse will not help.

Comment: Damn auto-correct!  What does "grazy" mean?